# Materialize CSS - getting a badge to left align?

Tags: css, materialize

Here's a code pen example: https://codepen.io/dsudomoin/pen/xxVorwW

[image]

Trying to get the red "should always be left" to left align (and vice-versa for the blue right) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Things I've tried: putting `left-align` and `left` in the class of the span and the div.

```
<ul id="provider-results" class="collapsible popout">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">Clare 
      <span data-badge-caption="should always be left" class="new badge red">1</span></div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">Denise 
      <span data-badge-caption="should always be left" class="new badge red">1</span>
      <span class="new badge blue" data-badge-caption="should always be right">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <div><b>will_see_hard_of_hearing</b>: If it is easy to get a translator</div>
      <div><b>some other criteria</b>: and then the note is here</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `.badge` class has a left margin by default. This will align your `.red` to the left.

```
.collapsible span.badge.red {
   margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for. But how do I add a bit of padding between the div text and the left-bound badge?

Comment: Change the last `0` to whatever you need. Eg. `margin: 0 auto 0 15px;`

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose you could add two custom classes with the following css.

```
.custom-align-left{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.custom-align-right{
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Please notice, that the badge will be next to texts in the collapsible (no margin between them). When you want some space between them, there are two possibilities:

**1:** Wrapping your text into a `span` and add a `padding-right` or `margin-right` to it. For instance:

`<span class="some-margin-right">Clare</span>`

```
.some-margin-right{
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

**2:** Editing the `margin-left` property in the class `custom-align-left` mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Adding `custom-align-left` to the badge span class only moves it into the middle, not right next to the name as expected.

Comment: Sure you defined the class correctly? I tried it with your codepen and it does work well. Maybe try to add an important flag, for instance ````margin-right: 0 !important;````. **Edit:** Added a picture for evidence.